# LDAP Java - Search for group membership across trusted domains

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap

There are two external forest trusted domains: *DomainA* and *DomainB*.

DomainA contains Global Groups *GG-1* and *GG-2*, and Users are member of these groups:

- U1 memberOf GG-1
- U2 memberOf GG-2

DomainB contains Domain Local Group *DLG-1* and groups *GG-1* and *GG-2* are members of this group.

Now when U1 is authenticated against *DomainA* we expected to get the membership of both GG-1 and DLG-1 but we are getting only GG-1.

Is there anyway we can identify the cross-domain group memberships of the user directly or indirectly using Java?

Answer (score 1):

If you use Java, that means you are using LDAP to query Active Directory. What you want will not work using the default LDAP port.

However, if you query the *Global Catalog* on port `3268` using LDAP it is possible to retrieve cross-domain memberships.

**EDIT**: If this does not yield any results, either you need a Universal Group (not likely) or the GC needs to be set up properly.

**EDIT2**: Given that you do not have a GC, the only other option is to create a referral object in AD that points to the external domain. See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/241737 how to set this up.

You then have to configure your Java LDAP environment to follow referrals like this: `env.put(Context.REFERRAL, "follow");`.

Comment: The environment is without GC and with only external two-way trust.

Comment: I just thought of another option, using referrals. See my second edit above. Good luck!